# Get SQL*Plus out in a file w/out "SQL>" line prefixes

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I am trying to get SQL*Plus to write progress in its out file that should be somewhat presentable as a report, i.e. not have undesirable formatting native to the application.  In particular, I would like to get rid of SQL> that every line seems to start with.  This is my shell script that invokes sqlplus:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

$ORABIN/sqlplus $ORADBUSER/$ORADBPASSWD@$ORADB<<!!>./orclTest.log

SELECT 'IN sqlplus' AS MESSAGE1 FROM dual;


VARIABLE rowCnt number;
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO :rowCnt FROM dual;
END;
/

SELECT 'Dual has ' || :rowCnt || ' rows' AS MESSAGE2 FROM  dual;


!!
```

When I run it, this is what I get in orclTest.log:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Production on Mon Oct 22 18:06:02 2012

Copyright (c) 1982, 2006, Oracle.  All Rights Reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Data Mining
and Real Application Testing options

SQL> SQL>
MESSAGE1 
----------
IN sqlplus

SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL>   2    3    4
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SQL>
MESSAGE2
------------------------------------------------------
Dual has 1 rows
```

Any way to tell sqlplus not to give me its standard formatting, like the header and prefixes and only output:

```
MESSAGE1 
----------
IN sqlplus


MESSAGE2
------------------------------------------------------
Dual has 1 rows
```

Comment: While you're at it : pass username password as parameters to your call to sqlplus. 'sqlplus /nolog username password sid' and do a 'connect &1/&2@&3' in side the SQL part. This way your username and password don't show up in the proces list. 'ps -ef | grep sqlplus'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to omit the `SQL>` prompt

```
 set sqlprompt ''
```

If you want to remove the numbers that are printed to denote subsequent lines in a multi-line statement

```
set sqlnumber off
```

Comment: thanks, that worked.  but how do i get rid of things like "2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18    2    3    4" that sometimes get displayed after SQL> (not in this example)?

Comment: got another one for ya:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13038825/config-sqlplus-to-return-nothing-but-data.  check it out.  thanks !