# Config SQL*Plus to return nothing but data

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, plsql, sqlplus

I need to write a simple shell function that returns a single field from an Oracle DB.  Think of it as for example `SELECT 'ABC' FROM dual;` and ABC is what I am after.

Here is my function:

```
function getSomeOraVal
{
sqlplus $USER/$PASSWD@$ORADB<<!!

SET sqlprompt '' 
SET sqlnumber off 

SET verify off
SET pages 0
SET echo off
SET head on
SET feedback off
SET feed off
SET serveroutput on
SET escape '\'

VARIABLE  v_someVal VARCHAR2(30);

BEGIN
SELECT 'ABC' INTO v_someVal FROM dual;
END;
/

SELECT :v_someVal FROM dual;

!!
}
```

However, I want to pipe the sqlplus output (data only -> 'ABC') into a shell variable, which the function then returns and can be called from other shell scripts.  Unfortunately, sqlplus returns a whole lot of garbage, such as "Welcome to Oracle" on top and "Disconnected..." in the bottom.

How can I extract just the data from a SQL result set, or in this case a single value and pass it into a UNIX variable for further manipulation within the shell?

Thanks

Comment: normally, i would do this in Perl but our Oracle::DBI libs are broken on my solaris box ...  so i have to make my script in just shell...

Comment: I think you want to use `set serveroutput off` (for starters). There are a lot of `set` commands that control the output from oracle. search here for `[bash] [oracle] sqlnumber` and you should find some other things you'll need to turn on or off. Oracle gurus are welcome to submit the correct answer ;-) Good luck to all.

Comment: `set serveroutput off` didn't do but thanks for trying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different approaches in this askTom thread on [returning values from SQL*Plus to a shell script](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:430819636473).

One common approach is to select a constant token in addition to the value that you want to return (in Tom's example, that is the string "KEEP") and then use sed (or your favorite command-line parser) to extract the data you're actually interested in

```
#!/bin/ksh

x=`sqlplus / <<endl | grep KEEP | sed 's/KEEP//;s/[   ]//g'
select 'KEEP' , max(sal) from emp;
exit
endl`

echo the answer is $x
```

Other approaches, such as approaches that allow you to [read multiple lines of output](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:430819636473#43031707677401) are also discussed in that thread.

If you don't want the header to be printed, you should be specifying

```
set head off
```

in your SQL*Plus script-- I'm not sure why you're explicitly setting the header on in the script if you don't want the header...  Do you want to keep some part of the header?

Comment: `set head off` didn't do, I still get the top and bottom header.  i had it on because i though that would give me column headings, which i do want.

Comment: another one for you, brother:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040679/parameterizing-table-name-in-sqlplus-input-file

Answer (score 1):

Based on Justin's answer (which is great), when you only need to select one number (or token), I consider this a little shorter, yet more readable version:

```
x=`sqlplus -S / <<< "select 'KEEP' , max(sal) from emp;" | awk '/KEEP/{print $2}'`
```