# Call PL/SQL with API which returns multiple output from shell script

Tags: bash, oracle, shell, plsql

I need to the below operations inside shell script and get the output in a variable.

```
p_message_code:= 'XXSYM_NON_PROD';    
                CBS_EMAIL_UTIL.GET_EMAIL_ADDR( p_message_code => p_message_code
                                         ,p_message_status => 'ALL'
                                         ,P_OU_ID => g_operating_unit
                                         ,x_from_email => x_from_email
                                         ,x_to_email => x_to_email
                                         ,x_cc_email => x_cc_email
                                         ,x_bcc_email => x_bcc_email
                                         );

           l_recipients := RTrim(x_to_email,',') ||','||RTrim(x_cc_email,',')||','||RTrim(x_bcc_email,',');
           l_recipients := sym_get_emails_from_DL(l_recipients);
```

I know how to get it for a single output - but I need to get from three variables , how could we get these **three** get `l_recipients` to a unix variable, any pointers or sample code will be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know [how to get the result of SQLPLUS into a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13039070/6019417), what you could do is get all into a single variable, separated with `,`, then process the result within the shell;

```
 string=#(how you get your result for one variable)
 recipients=$(echo "$string" | sed 's/,/ /g')
 set -- $recipients 
 rec_to=$1
 rec_cc=$2
 rec_bc=$3
```

get your result from PLSQL:

```
string=`sqlplus / <<endl 
  set serveroutput on
  set feedback off

  begin
    -- your code
    dbms_output.put_line(l_recipients);
  end;
/
endl`
```